# ns modification and compiling error

Tags: tcl, ns2

i am working on ns-allinone-2.35 . and i modified the aodv protocol that located on /ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/aodv folder. i do make clean , then make, every thing is ok.
but i notice that no changing in the result.
and i notice that if i change all aodv code to comments, the TCL file will running even if delete the aodv.o.

can any one help to specify exactly where is the changing on ns-allinone-2.35?          and from where the TCL file read the routing protocol?

Answer (score 0):

---

»»

> **the TCL file will running even if delete the aodv.o**

««

Files{.cc, .h, .o}, etc. in the ns-2.35/ folder are not used at simulation time. ( Exceptions : Some simulations can/will use some traffic files, e.g. from tcl/mobility/** ).

All functions from the c++ files (and tcl/lib/files*) are compiled into one file : 'ns'.

Files used by the executable 'ns' are the these only :
ns-allinone-2.35/{ lib/**, bin/tclsh8* }.

---

Changes : Be aware that ns2 speaks "otcl". And that all the (o)tcl functions in tcl/lib/ are also compiled into the executable 'ns'.

So may be your new function is missing in tcl/lib/{ files.tcl } ?

---